# filter data after ajax call using kendo ui

Tags: kendo-ui

In the following ajax call,i have data in result,now i want to filter my result:

```
      $.ajax({
          dataType: "json",
          type: "POST",
          url: "@Url.Action("method", "controller")",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          data: JSON.stringify({ "regionalManager": dtDrpVals.drpValue}),
          success: function (result) {       
              var rst = new kendo.data.DataSource({
              data: result,
              filter: [
    { field: "presented_in_class", operator: "eq", value: "false" },
    { field: "passed_course", operator: "eq", value: "false" }
          ]
      });
```

is the way i should filter ajax call?if so,why the filter is not working,i still get the same data

Comment: this link should hopefully help: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/filter#filter.filters you want to use the filter.filters property when applying multiple filters at the same time.

Comment: The shown filter should be doing an evaluation equivalent to `(!presented_in_class && !passed_course)`.  Can you show the json sent back to the component from the controller ?

Comment: you're filtering by  a string "false" did you try to filter  with `value:false` ?

Answer (score 1):

The configuration property `filter` value is either

- a single filter clause, or
- a composite filter clause

A single filter clause is an object with three properties

- `field`
- `operator`
- `value`

A composite filter clause is an object with two properties

- `logic`, `"and"` or `"or"`
- `filters`, an array of filters to be evaluated conjunctively using the logic value

  - the filters can be any mix of single or composite filters.

If logic is not specified it will default to `"and"`.

I presume the top level configuration `filter:` value is specially examined.  If the value is an array, the value will be considered a composite filter with logic `and`

The composite form allows nested logic such as `( A or (B and C) or (D and (E or F)) )`